# Applying full auto-format to comments but not code

Tags: formatting, comments

I am considering using Vim's `auto-format` feature (i.e., adding `a` to `formatoptions`).  However, I can't seem to figure out a combination of options that will give me the configuration that I want.  For reference, I am using Vim 8.1 (from May 18, 2018).

I mainly use Vim for coding, and obviously I only want to automatically format comments.  When writing comments alone, then `formatoptions=acoqr` seems to give me exactly what I want.

For code, I also want Vim to force me to break a line after `textwidth` has been reached, but I do not want it to reformat whole paragraphs when lines are edited.  Using `formatoptions=t` seems to give me the behavior that I want.

However, if I try to combine the two, with `formatoptions=acoqrt`, then Vim starts to reformat whole blocks of code as well as comments.  This seems to contradict the information in `:help fo-table`, which states:

```
a       Automatic formatting of paragraphs.  Every time text is inserted or
        deleted the paragraph will be reformatted.  See |auto-format|.
        When the 'c' flag is present this only happens for recognized
        comments.
```

That is, I would expect that since I am including `c` in `formatoptions`, then the auto-formatting behavior should apply to comments, and the ordinary `t` behavior (inserting newlines but not reformatting whole paragraphs) should apply to code.

Am I missing something?  Is this a bug?  If so, is there a workaround?